# C memcpy byte buffer to packed struct, good decision?

Tags: c, struct, memcpy

I am aware that type casting a buffer to struct is violating strict aliasing rule and that it's not portable

However is memcpy() a buffer to struct **with attribute packed** not voiding that rule, is it a good decision rather then parsing the contents of the buffer ? Lets keep in mind that both always have a fixed size

Comment: This attribute does nothing with regards to *strict aliasing* rule.

Comment: It depends on details of code use not discussed.  Post samples of the code expressing your ideas to add clarity.

Comment: I'll get back home and I'll try to post clarify it more

Comment: A *byte* buffer? That would be some `char []`? A `char *` is allowed to alias any other pointer, it's an explicit exception from the strict aliasing rule. So you can cast a pointer to your struct to `char *` -- and back as well as long as the original definition is "visible". For a real answer, **we need to see code**.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: OP does not say they expect the packed attribute to allow aliasing of the structure. They say they are copying the bytes to the packed structure using memcpy. Hence they insert the bytes into the structure using memcpy, which is supported by C, and then access the structure via its nominal type, which is support and which is not aliasing. (There is aliasing in that the bytes of the structure are accessed as bytes via memcpy, but that is supported.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I just stated that this specific attribute does not remove the rule violation in case it is already there, as aliasing and packing are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ensured that the packed structure lays out the bytes as desired on all the target platforms you wish to support, then copying the bytes into the structure via `memcpy` and then accessing them through the structure members is fine.

Depending on circumstances, it may be advisable to copy the structure members to a normal (not packed) structure for further use, so that unaligned members in the packed structure are not repeatedly accessed, which may be inefficient. Ultimately, this may be equivalent to issuing multiple `memcpy` calls to copy bytes from the buffer into individual members of the normal structure.

Using `memcpy` is certainly at least as efficient as parsing the buffer, as `memcpy` is about the simplest thing one can do with data. But whether it is more efficient or just the same depends on what sort of parsing you would be doing. Once you have the data in a structure, you will still have to operate on it in whatever ways your application requires anyway, so the `memcpy` would not seem to eliminate any real work that must be done.